# Android Studios stop logging entire phone

Tags: android-studio

When I connect my Android phone to my laptop, Android Studio goes crazy and starts logging EVERYTHING. It seems to literally pump out onto the console/logcat every signal from the phone.

Does anyone know how to turn this off, and only log messages when I'm debugging?

Answer (score 0):

you cant turn it off, you can hide it (shift+esc after clicking on log section) or filter it by string or type